# Can factor analysis improve the fit of a predictive regression model?

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, factor-analysis, goodness-of-fit, exploratory-data-analysis

My company is working with a client who have built a logistic regression model to predict whether kids with psychiatric disorders will successfully complete a State intervention program (Yes or No).

The regression revealed several significant demographic & medical diagnosis predictors, and a principal components analysis showed that several groups of variables were highly correlated with each other.

However, overall predictive fit of the model is fairly low (Nagelkerke R-square=.069), leading us to believe we could be missing important variables from the model (although we realize in the social sciences an R-square > 40% is rare).

Without actually collecting more data and variables, would an **exploratory factor analysis** improve the model's goodness-of-fit (i.e., increase the Nagelkerke R-square) by identifying latent variables more predictive of successful completion? Or is factor analysis more of an explanatory tool that doesn't improve goodness of fit?

Comment: Where would those "latent variables" come from? If you're trying to create them from linear combinations of the existing variables, then you will accomplish nothing.

Comment: To expand the comment. Factor scores given by EFA are linear functions of the variables and are only approximations. True factor values are unknown. If we knew them - then potentially yes, FA could help you to refine important predictive information and to enhance subsequent prediction both numerically and substantively.